# variance threshold, returning the names of the selected features

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying the variance threshold method for the first time and I am following the example in sklearn to work on it.

```
>>> X = [[0, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3]]
>>> selector = VarianceThreshold()
>>> selector.fit_transform(X)
array([[2, 0],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 1]])
```

However, at the end, it only returns an array of the values of the selected features. How can I get the name of the features that met the variance threshold limit here? I just need the names of the selected features.

Answer (score 2):

Use `selector.get_support` ([Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html#sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.get_support)).
This will give you a mask of the features that were selected and features that were discarded.

```
>>> selector.get_support()
array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

And here is how you get your selected features indices

```
>>> [ i for i, f in enumerate(selector.get_support()) if f ]
[1, 2]
```